# mutt (neomutt) can't access/show plain text attachment (body of message)

Tags: mutt, neomutt

When trying to open/read an inline `text/plain` attachment (the body of a plain-text message) of a received message from the `Attachments` view in (Neo)mutt, I'm getting:

```
sh: /tmp/neomutt-x1-1000-1595035-6095510368090236182: Permission denied
Press any key to continue...
```

When I try to view the file from the terminal, it works fine:

```
$ cat /tmp/neomutt-x1-1000-1595035-6095510368090236182
Hi ...
[msg body]
```

This problem doesn't occur when I try to view/open an inline `text/plain` attachment from the `Compose` view. Then it is normally displayed in the built-in `Pager`.

There's also no problem with viewing `text/html` or any other attachments.

Comment: You probably have a mis-configured mailcap file: the shell seems to be trying to execute the text file instead of displaying it via cat or less.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think the mailcap file is the problem. The respective line is `text/plain; $EDITOR %s ;`. Also, as mentioned above, the viewing works fine when initiated from the `Compose` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the exact issue, and in my case, my mailcap file had:

```
text/plain; $EDITOR %s ;
```

and my `EDITOR` variable wasn't set, so in effect Neomutt was attempting to run the text file as an executable.

Setting the EDITOR variable should fix the problem, or what I did is just change that line to:

```
text/plain; less %s ;
```

which worked perfectly. I use `vim` for composing mails, but wanted to use `less` for viewing plain text attachments, so that when viewing a plain text attachment to one of my own drafts I don't inadvertently start editing the text of a temporary file used only for viewing. :-)